# What is a political mind?

Tags: political-philosophy

The one which can manipulate the emotions of someone and can crave the frontier as per its choice.
I exactly want to know its specialities and how it differ from a scientific mind.

Comment: What does “crave the frontier as per its choice” mean...? It might be helpful to spell out *exactly the problem you’re running into your research* — what hypotheses have you formed? What specifically would you like someone here to briefly explain?

Comment: Maybe useful : [George Lakoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Lakoff) 's [The Political Mind: A Cognitive Scientist's Guide to Your Brain and Its Politics](https://books.google.it/books/about/The_Political_Mind.html?id=oUd7a9OUgtAC&redir_esc=y) (2008).

Comment: Sorry, but even assuming that such a thing exists what does the question have to do with philosophy? [Psychological manipulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_manipulation) is not restricted to politics, and [Psychology SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com) or [Politics SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com) seem like more appropriate places to ask the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your distinction between *political mind* and *scientific mind* is similar to an ideological battle that played out between [Socrates](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Socrates) and a group we now call [Sophists](http://www.iep.utm.edu/sophists/).

Sophists taught that in order to win an argument, you wait for the right moment (or *kairos*) and then tell somebody what you want them to believe.  Cultivating this kind of rhetorical persuasion was an art that helped many famous people and politicians at the time to gain political power and influence, and to get rich.

Socrates taught that if an idea is wrong, it's wrong no matter how or when you say it, or who is saying it.  According to Socrates, if someone wants you to believe them they need to answer your questions.  And if they can't answer your questions, they are wrong.

It seems to me that *the scientific mind* is kind of similar to Socrates, and *the political mind* is kind of similar to sophistry.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

▻ SCIENTIFIC VS POLITICAL MIND

At a very basic level of generality 'the scientific mind' is focused on description, explanation, prediction and retrodiction. 'The political mind' is centred rather on, in Harold LaSswell's formula, 'Politics: Who Gets What, When, How' (1936). Pretty well all political policies, laws, decisions, determine who gets what, when, and how - whatever other consequences they may have.

Lasswell puts the emphasis on distribution - on the allocation of benefits and burdens. It omits what one might call 'expressive' politics, where a policy is adopted not with a view to distribution but to its propaganda value or its embodiment of principle such as respect for international law. Political policies can also reinforce or undermine moral values as in policies regarding euthanasia and abortion.

▻ HOMO POLITICUS

But it seems to me that you are interested not only or even mainly in the conceptual characterisation of politics but also and chiefly in the psychology of politicians.

Try this out for its plausibility :

> In the past, leadership scholars considered charisma, intelligence and other personality traits to be the key to effective leadership. Accordingly, these academics thought that good leaders use their inborn talents to dominate followers and tell them what to do, with the goal either of injecting them with enthusiasm and willpower that they would otherwise lack or of enforcing compliance. Such theories suggest that leaders with sufficient character and will can triumph over whatever reality they confront.
>
> In recent years, however, a new picture of leadership has emerged, one that better accounts for leadership performance. In this alternative view, effective leaders must work to understand the values and opinions of their followers—rather than assuming absolute authority—to enable a productive dialogue with followers about what the group embodies and stands for and thus how it should act. **By leadership, we mean the ability to shape what followers actually want to do, not the act of enforcing compliance using rewards and punishments.**
>
> Given that good leadership depends on constituent cooperation and support, this new psychology of leadership negates the notion that leadership is exclusively a top-down process. In fact, it suggests that to gain credibility among followers,
>   **leaders must try to position themselves among the group rather than above it**. In his use of everyday language—such as “hunt down” and “those folks”—Bush portrayed himself on 9/11 as a typical American able to speak for America.
>
> According to this new approach, **no fixed set of personality traits can assure good leadership because the most desirable traits depend on the nature of the group being led.** Leaders can even select the traits they want to project to followers. It is no accident, then, that Bush has often come across to Americans as a regular guy rather than as the scion of an elite East Coast Yale University
>   dynasty.
>
> **But far from simply adopting a group’s identity**, influential presidents or chief executives who employ this approach **work to shape that identity for their own ends.** Thus, Bush helped to resolve the mass confusion on 9/11 in a way that promoted and helped to forge a new national unity. Among other things, people wondered: Who or what was the target? New York? Washington? Capitalism? The Western world? Bush’s answer: America is under attack. By establishing this fact, he invoked a sense of a united nation that required
>   his leadership. (Stephen D. Reicher, S. Alexander Haslam and Michael J. Platow, 'The New Psychology of Leadership', Scientific American Mind, Vol. 18, No. 4 (August/September 2007), 24.)

Check this (esp. the set of sentences in bold) against the current US President - how far does it ring true ?

▻ IN SELF-DEFENCE

I realise that the scientfic mind would not generalise from a single instance or example. But I am not inviting this. Check the characterisation against one politician (rather well-known at present) and then against any number of other politicians.

▻ REFERENCES

Harold D. Lasswell, Politics: Who Gets What, When, How, NY, 1936 (rev. 1958 and often reprinted).

Stephen D. Reicher, S. Alexander Haslam and Michael J. Platow, 'The New Psychology of Leadership', Scientific American Mind, Vol. 18, No. 4 (August/September 2007), 22-9.

Comment: Can the same person have both political and scientific mind? Or are they distinct?

Comment: Yes, the same person can.